How can I migrate my configuration and applications to a fresh install of Ubuntu?
I recently tried to upgrade my Ubuntu system to 24.04.1 LTS from Jammy Jellyfish. Unfortunately, It keeps failing and making my system unusable.
Since upgrading my system is no longer an option, is there a way to migrate my installed applications and configuration information over to a fresh install of Noble Numbat?
For anyone that's curious the link to my issues upgrading my systems is
Failed upgrade from 22.04.4 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS with the error message "could not install gconf2"
Thanks in advance!

It's now commercial software but aptik works a treat https://store.teejeetech.com/product/aptik/ (No affliliation, just a user)

Simple manual rsync & rdiff theFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2471454&p=14078689#post14078689
Restore process TheFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474107&p=14091927#post14091927bbI first export list of installed apps into /home, so list is backed up also. Similar https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=868244&page=2&p=7015603#post7015603 Apps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReinstallingSamePackages  & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/list-explicitly-installed-packages

Aptik looks wonderful, I may have to purchase it and do that if i cant figure out how to upgrade my system in week or so. @oldfred How involved is the process of using rsync and rdiff? I haven't used either of them yet. All i'm using now is duplicity and clonezilla for full image backups.

Once I started using rsync I regularly use it to copy system to various drives. Not best backup process like rdiff would be, but I have multiple copies at various times. I believe links above have example scripts, I started small with just rsync of /home. Later I converted to data partition(s) and rsync those by updating my scripts. I think rdiff works better but probably best then to have separate server for backup. First new install I did, I did not have list of installed apps, bit mistake as I had added a lot of apps.

I used Aptik from https://store.teejeetech.com/product/aptik/ and it worked great. You do have to pay for it but it was worth it based on the time it saved me.
